# how to give the adress of subdomain on gunicorn_config file

Tags: django, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy a django app. I a
m using gunicorn . I used

gunicorn_config.py :

```
command='/root/m/bin/gunicorn'
pythonpath='/root/m'
bind='xxxxxx.net'
workers=3
```

for the main domain which works well but for subdomain named admin. I tried
bind = 'admin.xxxxx.net'  which doesn't works
bind = 'xxxx.net/admin' which also doesn't works.

Can anyone help how to write bind for subdomain

Comment: i think, you need first to define your subdomain `admin.xxxxx.net` in `vhost` conf (`apache` or `nginx`)

Comment: my comment above was useful for you, if so i'll move it to be an answer ? if not, did you find a solution ? let me know

Comment: Ii didn't find any solution and i don't understand how to do from ur comment. Any help highly useful for me. Kindly answer

Comment: maybe if we look from an other angle, why not using `django-hosts` package to handle subdomains (`xxxxx.net`, `admin.xxxxx.net`, `blog.xxxxx.net` and so on) and in your `gunicorn config you set `bind=xxxxx.net` the main domain. have a look at this repo it may help you https://github.com/cizario/subdomain-demo. let me know if that helps you